Installing nonfree packages on Parabola
I've got an install of parabola running on a virtual machine, and I'd like to install the virtualbox-guest-utils package.
Unfortunately it's in the Arch [extra] repo, and Parabola already has an [extra] repo. Is there any way to rig up pacman so that it will search the Arch repos after failing to find a package in the parabola repos? I was thinking that maybe I could maintain my local cache AND db file under a different name like [arch-extra], but I can't find any information on doing that.

Arch and parabola are independent rolling release distros. And they are arch, so dependency version enforcement isn't happening.
You must not just mix and match repos; they get rebuilt from dependencies at different paces, so that you would end up with incompatible binaries.
So, sorry, from a technical perspective, this is too fragile, and mustn't be done.
Also, you're running a distro whose goal specifically is to not include non-libre guest extensions. So, if you still want to install them, maybe switch to the original Arch Linux.
What you could do is figure out how the package in Arch's extra repo is built, and replicate that locally. I'd still be wondering why you'd be using a distro that takes a relatively extreme stand on what is "free" and "non-free" and then install proprietary software on it.

I want to start with free software and make specific exceptions as necessary/desired. I suppose your point about dependencies is valid. There's a post buried on the Parabola subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/ebgniw/deleted_by_user/ that suggests starting with Arch and granting the Parabola specific repos (e.g. [libre]) precedence.
As a mere intellectual exercise the closest solution I have so far is to hard-code a server for say [arch-core] into pacman.conf, and then pulling core.db from the repo with curl.
Thanks for your thoughts!

please, again, don't do that, you'll be just getting broken packages. I have pointed out a technically viable method in my answer.
